# Why does Safari's document.adoptNode() convert css class names to lowercase when source document is in quirks mode?

Tags: javascript, dom, safari

I am using XHR (XML Http Request) to load an html fragment. I am using responseType = "document" in order to offload the html parsing to the browser. When the ajax call completes, I am using document.adoptNode() to include the ajax html elements in my main document.

I noticed a weird bug that affects Safari only (v9.1.1 on El Capitan and iOS 9.3.2). It seems that when Safari adopts the node, it will convert css class names into lower case. For a full demonstration, see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/theblueslate/wxo7zst5/2/

This bug doesn't occur on Chrome v51 or IE11.

The code from the jsfiddle is included here:

```
function buildDataLoadedCallback (containerId, useAdopt) {
    return function() {
        var parsedDoc = this.response;
        var parsedBodyChild = parsedDoc.body.children[0];

        var newNode;

        if (useAdopt) {
            newNode = document.adoptNode(parsedBodyChild);
        } else {
            newNode = document.importNode(parsedBodyChild, true);
        }
        var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
        container.appendChild(newNode);
    }

}

function requestAjaxHtmlFragment(pageName, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = "document";
    xhr.addEventListener("load", callback);

    /* this fragment.html file simply contains:
    <div class="myClass">
    <p>MyClass</p>
    </div>
    */
    xhr.open("GET","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15211879/js-fiddle/" + pageName + ".html", /*async:*/true);

    xhr.send();
}

var pageName =  "fragment";

requestAjaxHtmlFragment(pageName, buildDataLoadedCallback(pageName + "-adopt-container", true));
```

Is there an obvious error that I am missing? I can't spot it, and I have raised a webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=159555, but I am hoping I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug. Now fixed in WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=159555

I think it is still useful posting this to SO. Posting increases the visibility for anybody else who is struggling with this issue, as I was.